# Python-Dictionary from file with two keys and multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary

(This question has been answered in a couple of previous posts on stackoverflow. However, I cannot get the right result and I cannot figure what am I doing wrong?)

I would like to create a dictionary from a text file that contains two keys and 14 values:

```
data.txt:

Key1    Key2    Val1    Val2    Val3…Val14
100       a     x0      y0      z0………n0
101       a     x1      y1      z1………n1
102       b     x2      y2      z2………n2
103       b     x3      y3      z3………n3
104       c     x4      y4      z4………n4
105       c     x5      y5      z5………n5
…
140       m     xm      ym      zm………nm
```

The dictionary should look like this:

```
{100: {a: [x0, y0, z0,…n0]},
101: {a: [x1, y1, z1,…n1]},
102: {b: [x2, y2, z2,…n2]},
103: {b: [x3, y3, z3,…n3]},
 …
140: {m: [xm, ym, zm,…nm]}}
```

I have tried Code1 and Code2. Code1 gives a very large dictionary where lines are repeated with other lines appended to them. Code2 gives the error TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice’.

```
Code1:
lookupfile = open("data.txt", 'r')
lines = lookupfile.readlines()
lookup = lines[1:]   # Start the dictionary from row 1, exclude the column names
d={}
for line in lookup:
    dic = line.split()
    d.update({dic[0]: {dic[1]: dic[2:]}})
    print(d) 

Code2:
data = defaultdict(dict)
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        data[row['Key1']][row['Key2']]=row['Val1':]
        print (data)
```

I would prefer the code to look like Code2, so I can later use the column names. 
But, I would appreciate any help.

I can provide additional information, if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s="""Key1    Key2    Val1    Val2    Val3…Val14
100       a     x0      y0      z0
101       a     x1      y1      z1
102       b     x2      y2      z2
103       b     x3      y3      z3
104       c     x4      y4      z4
105       c     x5      y5      z5"""
d  = {}
for line in s.splitlines()[1:]:
    spl = line.split()
    d[spl[0]] ={spl[1]:spl[2:]}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(d)
{'100': {'a': ['x0', 'y0', 'z0']},
 '101': {'a': ['x1', 'y1', 'z1']},
 '102': {'b': ['x2', 'y2', 'z2']},
 '103': {'b': ['x3', 'y3', 'z3']},
 '104': {'c': ['x4', 'y4', 'z4']},
 '105': {'c': ['x5', 'y5', 'z5']}}
```

The same logic applies in your file code, to skip the first line call `next` on the file object. Then simply index each row as above.

```
d = {}
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    next(f) # skip header
    for row in f:
        spl = line.split()
        # slicing using spl[2:] will give you a list of all remaining values
        d[spl[0]] = {spl[1]:spl[2:]}
```

If  you actually have multiple spaces between your columns using `str.split` will work better than using the csv module.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I do get a better result now. But I still get too many lines than the number of lines I have in my document, with some lines being repeated/appended to other lines. Can it be something wrong with my input file? It is a text with spaces in between columns. Thank you!

Comment: There must be an issue with your file. This as posted would not cause repeated lines

Comment: I see. Can you please suggest a way to create my input file? I have copied the values from the data posted here to a text file, ran it with your code, and I get the same repeated lines. I usually save my files "as text" from Excel. Does this create a problem? I cannot post here the result I get because of lack of characters. Again, thank you!

Comment: iterate over your file with `for ind,_ in enumerate(f):print(ind)` and see what the actual lines count is.

Comment: If you can paste a link to your file that would help too

Comment: There were 5 lines. But I still had the "print" inside the for loop so it was printing after every iteration. It was easier to see this with the smaller file. Sorry about that and thank you for the help!

Comment: @Brebenel, no worries. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `DictReader`, so each `row` is a `dict`, and you can't slice a `dict` (as you're trying to do on the RHS of the assignment).

So use a plain `csv.reader` (so each `row` is a `list`, which you **can** slice) and:

```
data[row[0]][row[1]]=row[2:]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried with a simple reader and I get the error: TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method. I don't have all integers in my file. What should I do with the strings?

Comment: `data` is a `dict`, so is `data[row[0]]` -- the only list and the only slice is `row[2:]` where the index, `2`, clearly **is** an `int`.  So the line I show cannot give the error (the only other change I recommended was `Reader` in lieu of `DictReader` and that can't give this error either!).  You must have changed something else in addition (or **not** changed the indexing as I clearly showed in this answer).

Comment: It might be a problem with the Reader. Do you mean I should change reader = csv.DictReader(file) to reader = csv.Reader(file)? This didn't work so I tried reader = pd.read_csv(file, sep=" "), which worked but with wrong results. I would be curious to learn what you meant by Reader, but I would not want to waste your time as I have managed to run the code with the help from previous answers. I appreciate the answer, though. Thank you.

Comment: I did mean `csv.reader(file)` (lowercase `r`) and with the integer indices I also suggest it works fine.

Comment: I tried it and I still have an error. So I am pretty sure I am doing something else wrong. But I don't want to waste your time so I will leave it be as I managed to run another version of the code. Thank you, though!